# get out the value by using a key in the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

with my code i have problem to get out the value , which is number of words by using a key the word it self 
that is my code ,

```
 public static void essintial(string UserCorpus, string word)
    {
       // string str = "Alameer Ashraf Hassan Alameer ashraf,elnagar.";

        string[] CorpusResult = UserCorpus.Split(' ', ',', '.');

       //Creating the Dictionary to hold up each word as key & its occurance as Value  ......! 
        Dictionary<string, int> Dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

       //looping over the corpus and fill the dictionary in .........!
        foreach (string item in CorpusResult)
        {
            if (item != "")
            {
                if (Dict.ContainsKey(item) == false)
                {
                    Dict.Add(item, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    Dict[item]++;
                }
            }
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(Dict);
        foreach (var item in Dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }


        int ss = Dict[word];
        Console.WriteLine(ss);
}
```

there is a problem to get out the key.

Comment: "there is a problem" - what problem? Did you mean to do `foreach (var item in Dict) { Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value); }`?

Comment: thank you the problem was , when i tried to enter the word i follow it with space character which make unmatched word .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what issue you're having exactly, but I have an idea.
One issue may be the word that you provide is not in the dictionary. That could cause a `KeyNotFoundException`. A simple fix would be something like:

```
if(Dict.ContainsKey(word)){
    Console.WriteLine(Dict[word]);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine(0); //Or whatever you deem appropriate
}
```

The other issue you may have is that the `foreach(var item in Dict)`.  Dictionaries iterate over the pairs of elements. The variable `item` has an inferred type of `KeyValuePair<string,int>` and `Console.WriteLine(item);` may not be printing what you expect.  Try replacing `Console.WriteLine(item)` with `Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " +item.Value);`

Comment: completely helpful and the problem solved , thanks @drg

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```csharp
string str = "Alameer Ashraf Hassan Alameer ashraf,elnagar.";

        string[] CorpusResult = str.Split(' ', ',', '.');

       //Creating the Dictionary to hold up each word as key & its occurance as Value  ......! 
        Dictionary<string, int> Dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

       //loopnig over the corpus and fill the dictionary in .........!
        foreach (string item in CorpusResult)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) continue;

            if (Dict.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                Dict[item]++;
            }
            else
            {
                Dict.Add(item, 1);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Method 1: ");
        foreach (var item in Dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Method 2: ");
        foreach(var k in Dict.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Dict[k]);
        }
```

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JZ9Eid